# Searching a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, search

OK Ive been able to get the following to partially work

```
var Global_Wound_array =[{"WoundNumber":1,"BodySide":"Front","BodyPart":"Nose"},{"WoundNumber":2,"BodySide":"Left","BodyPart":"Head"},{"WoundNumber":3,"BodySide":"Back","BodyPart":"Ear"}]
var Global_Wound_Counter = 1
```

I can get the page to loop through and display the individual wounds but I need a way to say at a particular page one of the values eg on WoundNumber 2 BodyPart has changed and updated the string without affecting the rest of it.

```
page9200.setEventHandler("pageFinishing", function () {
//getSelectedButtonLabel this is ok - specific on the system
let Q1 = Q3_WoundNumber.getValue();
let Q2 = Q1_BodySide.getSelectedButtonLabel();
let Q3 = Q2_BodyPart.getSelectedButtonLabel();
for (var i = 0; i < Global_Wound_array.length; i++) {               
if (i+1 == Q1){ 
//create new temp variable array
var Temp_Wound_obj2 = {"WoundNumber": Q1,"BodySide": Q2,"BodyPart":Q3}    
Global_Wound_array.push(Temp_Wound_obj2)
}
}
});
```

As well as being able to reach the end of the string to present a blank set of values to have the option to add a new wound.
Every time I think Ive got something that looks like it would work I go around in circles, when I try to update the system at the end I get and error that the - invaid parameters for RPC call: variable is bad

Comment: The code isn't valid. Do you mean `"[{\"WCount\":1,\"Side\":\"Centre\",\"Part\":\"Ocipit\",\"Type\":\"Other\",\"SurroundingSkin\":\"Dermatitis\",\"Height\":\"\",\"Width\":\"\",\"Depth\":\"\"}][{\"WCount\":2,\"Side\":\"Front\",\"Part\":\"Neck\",\"Type\":\"Diabetic foot wound\",\"SurroundingSkin\":\"Healthy/intact\",\"Height\":\"3\",\"Width\":\"4\",\"Depth\":\"5\"}]"`?

Comment: You _almost_ seem to have a correct JSON string. If so, regex is a wrong tool, use `JSON.parse`. If not, I suggest fixing the code that produces the string to make sure it is a correct JSON string. Either way, as @jabaa commented, the way your quotes are arranged, your code does not make sense, and it is hard for us to have confidence in exactly what your string looks like; please make sure to create a [example] that we can execute without an error (`const string = "your string here"`). And in particular, is what you posted one string, or two?

Comment: Yes sorry it is intended to be JSON string at the end

Comment: Yes sorry it supposed to be JSON string The code to create it is 
var ThisWoundDataObj = [{"WCount": WoundNumber, "Side": WSide, "Part": WPart, "Type": WType, "SurroundingSkin": WSurroundingSkin, "Height": WHeight, "Width": WWidth, "Depth": WDepth}];                                   
                    let theString = (JSON.stringify(ThisWoundDataObj));
the string is stored when file is closed and pulled back if the file is re-run. The reason for running the file again is be to add another set of values to the string, I need to read the last value for WCount and increase it by 1.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are pasting JSON onto JSON, with no separator. This creates a messy and non-standard data structure. If you wrote your JSON with a newline at the end, you would end up with a [JSONL](https://jsonlines.org/) file, which is very simple to process.

```js
const jsonl = `
[{"WCount":1,"Side":"Centre","Part":"Ocipit","Type":"Other","SurroundingSkin":"Dermatitis","Height":"","Width":"","Depth":""}]
[{"WCount":2,"Side":"Front","Part":"Neck","Type":"Diabetic foot wound","SurroundingSkin":"Healthy/intact","Height":"3","Width":"4","Depth":"5"}]
`;

const jsonItems = jsonl.trim().split("\n");
const lastJsonItem = jsonItems[jsonItems.length - 1];
const lastItem = JSON.parse(lastJsonItem);
const lastWCount = lastItem[0].WCount;
console.log(lastWCount);
```

If you already have a file without newlines... it would be best to insert them, and correct your data to JSONL. This is simple in your case just by replacing `][` with `]\n[` (and making sure the file ends with a newline too, so the next write would not be messed up), since you have no nesting and (hopefully) no `][` in your text, but in general it is not easy - I don't know of a JSON parser that will return unconsumed text, so it would probably involve writing a JSON parser. Much easier to write data correctly in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and example.a great help